# From given DE, comment on the nature of roots of the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I came across this problem where a DE is given as $u''+\frac{ku}{(2x+1)^2}=0$ and for this I had to judge the nature of roots of the solution and tell when they would be infinity, if $k>1, k<1, k<1/2$ or $k>1/2$ and I tried using Sturm theorem but it doesn't seem to work. Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "roots of the solution"? Do you mean the eigenvalues? That depends on the boundary conditions. Do you mean when there are multiple solutions?

Comment: No like let's suppose if the solution to the differential equation was sin(x-xo) {a non trivial solution} then it has infinite roots. In that sense

Comment: This is an Euler-Cauchy equation, you can write down the exact solution.